# How to insert an image into LaTeX document?

Tags: graphics

I have already included `graphicx` package and include

```
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{D:\ImagesforProjectLatex}}
 % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
 % every instance of \includegraphics
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
```

In the place that I want to insert the image I use the following example.

```
 \begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Example}
 \caption{A picture of the same gull
       looking the other way!}
 \end{figure}
```

I use the "LaTeX => DVI" option.
I am a newbie to LATeX, so I do not know the difference between "LaTeX => PDF" and "LaTeX => PS => PDF"
My ultimate goal is to convert the document into a pdf file. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: One immediate comment would be that the first line `\ifCLASSINFOpdf` is used to do stuff only when you are doing Latex=> pdf and be skipped elsewhere. And most probably it should be followed by a `\fi` if I remember correctly from the IEEE Transactions class file. So try to use the Latex=>PDF, as most of the commands you use are tailored towards PDF.

Comment: I think you should always use forward slashes `/` in paths, even on Windows.

Comment: Although I could see that a figure is formed due to its caption, I could not reach the image even if the directory is D://ImagesforProjectLatex/Example    what could be the problem?

Comment: @Hephaestus: Look at the answer in: [Paths and Linux/Windows slash conventions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18913/paths-and-linux-windows-slash-conventions). It is also valid for `\graphicspath`.

Comment: @Hephaestus --- What type of file is `Example` (i.e. eps/pdf/jpg, etc.)? Are any warning messages shown in the terminal when you compile the document?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Various pieces of your preamble are superfluous. Just use:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{D:\ImagesforProjectLatex}}
```

That will take care of choosing the right driver whether you're using `latex` (it will automatically select a driver suitable for `xdvi` and `dvips`) or `pdflatex`. No `\ifCLASSINFOpdf` is needed. Also, it sets the valid extensions automatically, so you don't have to do that either. Lastly, if you put the pdf-compatible image files and the dvi-compatible image files in the same directory, then you don't need to use the `\ifCLASSINFOpdf` conditional to set the right `\graphicspath`.

The `figure` code later on when you actually insert the image is completely correct. It's exactly what I use when I write.

Answer (score 11):

What I did: Convert any images to *.eps here: http://www.go2convert.com/ or with any commercial software you have for that.
You also need two packages, one standard for dealing with images and another one for converting from eps to pdf file while compile.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf} %%package to overcome problem with eps in pdf files


\begin{figure}
\centering
        \includegraphics[totalheight=8cm]{images/verticalcell.eps}
    \caption{used by \citet[p.~4]{XXXXX}.}
    \label{fig:verticalcell}
\end{figure}
```

or like that:

```
\begin{figure}[tph!]
\centerline{\includegraphics[totalheight=6cm]{images/verticalcell.eps}}
    \caption{used by \citet[p.~4]{XXXXX}.}
    \label{fig:verticalcell}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is an alternative way you can insert graphics into a TeX file on windows.

```
\centering

\includegraphics{`File Name`.`File extension type`}
```

**For Captions:**

```
\begin{center} 

Figure 1: A picture of the same gull looking the other way! 

\end{center}
```

Hope thats something of what your looking for, if not, leave a comment and I will be more than gladly to update my response.

Comment: Note that you can skip the file name extension and a set of extension will be tried automatically. Also `center` is often the wrong way to center an image. It adds some vertical spacing before and after which might or might not be wanted. For `figure`s `\centering` should be used instead.

Comment: -1: What's wrong with the `figure` environment?