# Graphics loading, latex and pdflatex differences

Tags: graphics, pdftex, external-files

I have a strange graphics loading problem which I can't explain. I have this simple file `docs/paper.tex`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./docs/}}
\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{teapot}
\end{document}
```

In the same directory as `docs/paper.tex` I have a file called `docs/teapot.png`. In my project root directory I call `pdflatex`:

```
$ /usr/bin/pdflatex docs/paper.tex
```

It works fine. However, if I call `latex`:

```
$ /usr/bin/latex docs/paper.tex
...
! LaTeX Error: File `teapot' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.656   \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{teapot}
```

Why does pdflatex and latex work differently here? And what is the right way to do it?

Comment: You cannot use `png`  figures with `latex`. That is the whole point.

Comment: Other  answers say that you can: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19176/how-to-insert-an-image-into-latex-document

Comment: Where, i cannot see it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21646/126379

Comment: This answer talks about *pdf-compatible image files* (png, jpg and pdf) and *dvi-compatible image files* (eps). png images won't work with `latex` (which is  `pdflatex` in `dvi-mode`).

Comment: According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17737/126379 it should work if you use the parameters `natwidth` and `natheight`. I tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: Never use that options unless you really know whats going on.