# Is there a 'try' command for LaTeX?

Tags: conditionals, input

What I'm trying to do is input *file1* if it exists and input *file2* otherwise, without having to deal with an 'I can't find file' error. I would like to accomplish this using TeX, without using symbolic links. What I would like is some kind of `\try` command:

```
\try{\input{file1}}
\catch{\input{file2}}
```

Of course, this would try to input *file1* and, if it encounters an error, input *file2* instead.

I'm sure people who are more proficient than I am with plain TeX could accomplish this easily.

(Please feel free to edit the tags.)

Comment: There's an `\InputIfFileExists`, see e.g. [how do I use the \input command on windows, combined with \IfFileExists?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36511/36522#36522)

Comment: A poor man's attempt at conditioning: `\IfFileExists{fileA.tex}{\input{fileA.tex}}{\input{fileB.tex}}`; `\InputIfFileExists` does exactly this.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Should I close this question, then?

Comment: I dunno.  I think try/catch functionality in LaTeX would be useful, if possible.  I have my doubts though, since all the languages I can think off with that feature have a thin over-layer as sort of a dispatcher.