# Replace every backslash in a string with a forwardslash

Tags: tex-core, strings, xstring

I would like to replace every backslash `\` inside a macro (string) with a forwardslash `/`.

The macro is intended to contain a filename in Windows notation which should be replaced by a valid (La)TeX compatible filename. I know that it is preferable to process such strings before using them in a source file, but: is it possible to do it with (La)TeX?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% The following macro is a placeholder.
% It should replace '\' by '/'
% #1: input
% #2: output
\newcommand{\replaceBS}[2]{%
  \edef\x{\noexpand\edef\noexpand#2{\noexpand\detokenize{\expandonce#1}}}%
  \x%
}

\begin{document}

\def\WindowsFilename{c:\files\examples\pictures\myfile.png}

\replaceBS{\WindowsFilename}{\TeXFilename}

Current result: \texttt{\TeXFilename}

Expected result: \texttt{c:/files/examples/pictures/myfile.png}

\end{document}
```

A solution for `\replaceBS` should be compilable with `pdflatex`.

I've tried things with the `xstring` package so far without success. Any solution with TeX, LaTeX3, special packages,... is welcome.

And just to be sure: Yes, I know how to do a replacement with an editor or an external tool ;-)

Comment: I think, `xstring` will also help

Comment: Why do you want to replace the string? Wouldn't it be enough if it hadn't catcode 0?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I want to use the resulting string to include an image to the document.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I could'nt figure out how. But David came up with a very short and nice TeX solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\replaceBS}[2]{{\escapechar=`/ 
  \xdef#2{\expandafter\zap@space\detokenize\expandafter{#1} \@empty}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\WindowsFilename{c:\files\examples\pictures\myfile.png}

\replaceBS{\WindowsFilename}{\TeXFilename}

Current result: \texttt{\TeXFilename}

Expected result: \texttt{c:/files/examples/pictures/myfile.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I just tested successfully that the resulting `\TeXFilename` can be used to include images (or whatever). Thank you: that was fast :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I'm fairly sure that for that use you wouldn't have to change `\ ` to `/` just detokenize it.

Comment: Hmm... maybe, but that resulted in errors because detokenizing inserted spaces and the file could not be found.

Comment: Spaces in the path will be zapped as well, but they shouldn't be used anyway.

Comment: @egreg yes there's a hint in the `\zap@space` command name:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you see a way to preserve existing spaces in the path like `c:\my files\foo` to `c:/my files/foo`?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm they are not existing, if you use a command like `\my ` then the space is never tokenized at all it is absorbed while making the `\my` token so `\my1` and `\my 1` are identical input.  The only way to stop that is to change the catcode of `\ ` before taking the string. If you do `{\catcode'\Z=0 Zcatccode '\\=12 ZxdefZmystring{\c:\my a a \za}}` then `\mystring` will have spaces and safe backslashes without any replacement needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I have it now :-) With your hint about the catcode `\includegraphics` did work, but `\filename@parse` still had some problems. Catcode change plus `\replaceBS` from @egreg's answer combined had no problems. Thank you again!

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm ah well "whoever" wrote `\filename@parse` decided that windows users would use `/` so it doesn't attempt to split on `\ ` . I wonder who that was.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :-)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, both MiKTeX and TeX Live for Windows accept paths where `\` is replaced by `/`, so if you define your `\WindowsFilename` as

```
c:/files/examples/pictures/myfile.png
```

to begin with, you shouldn't have any problem.

However, I understand that the casual user might not know this and be used to DOS style paths.

If you don't plan to define the paths in the argument to other commands, you can use some `expl3` features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setWindowsPath}{mv}
 {
  \cs_new:Npn #1 { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\replaceBS}{mm}
 {
  \tl_set_eq:NN #2 #1
  \tl_replace_all:NVn #2 \c_backslash_other_tl { / }
 }
\tl_const:Nx \c_backslash_other_tl { \cs_to_str:N \\ }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setWindowsPath{\WindowsFilename}{c:\files\examples\pictures\myfile.png}

\replaceBS{\WindowsFilename}{\TeXFilename}

\show\WindowsFilename
\show\TeXFilename

\setWindowsPath{\WindowsFilenameS}{c:\files\example spaced\pictures\myfile.png}

\replaceBS{\WindowsFilenameS}{\TeXFilenameS}

\show\WindowsFilenameS
\show\TeXFilenameS
```

Note that this preserves spaces in paths. Note also that the backslashes in the Windows filenames have been “neutralized”, because they have category code 12.

```
> \WindowsFilename=\long macro:
->c:\files\examples\pictures\myfile.png.
l.22 \show\WindowsFilename

? 
> \TeXFilename=macro:
->c:/files/examples/pictures/myfile.png.
l.23 \show\TeXFilename

? 
> \WindowsFilenameS=\long macro:
->c:\files\example spaced\pictures\myfile.png.
l.29 \show\WindowsFilenameS

? 
> \TeXFilenameS=macro:
->c:/files/example spaced/pictures/myfile.png.
l.30 \show\TeXFilenameS
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for that answer which preserves spaces (and umlauts as I have tested). The intended use is for some Windows-generated data which may not be able to be filtered before input. Unfortunately, this would need the replacement to be inside another macros argument. Further, `\WindowsFilename` would have to be re-used many times which is not possible with the current code.

Comment: I will investigate if I can do the replacement somehow automatically before LaTeX comes into play.