# Errors in a two column document in LyX

Tags: bibtex, lyx, achemso

I am getting following errors when I select the two column option for ACS document class and link my bibtexstyle bibliography. The errors don't show when I have a single column document along with the bibliography or a two column style without the bibliography.

```
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 422 of file newfile2.aux

 \begin{mcitethebibliography}{38}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.

If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

I am working with Langmuir style (ACS). How to get my images in a single column while keeping the text in the two column format ?

Comment: This is nothing to do with having two columns: you've got a `\bibliographystyle` line in your source (`achemso` automatically adds one).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was identified by Joseph Wrigt in a comment: LyX adds `\bibliographystyle` to the document, but as `achemso` already does that, you get an error.

I think that to make this work you have to do two things:

1. First choose Insert --> Note --> Comment. Inside this comment-inset, add the bibliography the normal way, with Insert --> List/ToC --> BibTeX bibliography.

   This step allows you to add citations via the LyX GUI, but LaTeX ignores the `\bibliographystyle` that is added by LyX.
2. Add an ERT with Insert --> TeX Code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>), and write

   ```
   \bibliography{/full/path/to/your/bibfile}
   ```

   (Of course with the actual path to the bib-file on your system.) I'm guessing you need the full path because LyX generates temporary files with LaTeX code that it compiles.

Might look like this in LyX:

[image]

Comment: I did the same but am getting the error \begin{mcitethebibliography}{38}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.

If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Comment: @Curious Same error as you mention in the question? That shouldn't happen. In the error window that pops up, can you click on *View complete log* or whatever is says, and edit your question to include the entire log?

Comment: I have uploaded what I do here. my bibliography is called references. http://dropcanvas.com/ll57u

Comment: @Curious Fine, nothing wrong there, but what does the log file say?

Comment: I have attached the log file here, http://dropcanvas.com/sna0q

Comment: @Curious can you please post a minimal example .lyx file? See here for more information: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: I have added a lyx file as well as a bib file which gives me the errors. Here is the url: http://dropcanvas.com/oqnmf

Comment: @Curious It really is better to include such things directly in your question, rather than relying on external sites: Open the files in a text editor, copy all the text, and paste it into the question.

Comment: @Curious Works fine here. One thing I didn't think about earlier is that you may have to use `/` instead of `\` in the path (see [Paths and Linux/Windows slash conventions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18913)). Not sure why that would throw the error you mention though.

Comment: I am still not able to resolve it. It gives me errors:  ...raphy{C:\Users\MukulBhatnagar\Desktop\ref}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: and this:                                                                                                 ...raphy{C:\Users\MukulBhatnagar\Desktop\ref}
                                                  
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

Comment: @Curious In `1.lyx` you have backslashes in the path to the `.bib` file, try with forward slashes, as in your previous screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39615/discussion-between-curious-and-torbjorn-t).