# How to make image insertion platform independent?

Tags: graphics, ubuntu, ifplatform

When I wrote my LaTeX file in windows, I have just given the name of the image without extension to add it anywhere like the following.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{./img/varsityLogo}
\end{figure}
```

For the above lines in action, I put the image `varsityLogo.png` under the `img` sub-folder of the folder containing this file.

But when I went to compile it in ubuntu 16.04 LTS, it gives the following error.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `./img/varsityLogo' not found.
```

How to solve it? Should I edit all the paths of images and add corresponding extension like the code below? If yes, then is not there any way to make it platform independent?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{./img/varsityLogo.png}
\end{figure}
```

But it produces a new error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in ./img/varsityLogo.png (no Bo
undingBox).
```

What is the simplest way to resolve these issues while changing the platform?

Note that, my .tex file runs and produces pdf file without any error in windows.

Comment: the image formats supported do not depend on the operating system You are using pdflatex on windows and latex on linux. You would see the same error if you used latex on windows and it would work without error if you used pdflatex on linux

Comment: unrelated but you should not use `[h]` (normally it gives a warning and is turned into `[ht]` but `[htp]` makes it far less likely that the image goes to the end of the document.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your suggestion in second comment. Wow! Does there exist another package called pdflatex? How to install and use that? Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I got it. In the terminal instead of `latex <file_name>`, I had to use `pdflatex <file_name>`. However, Thanks once again. :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Should I delete this question?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Could you please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image formats supported do not depend on the operating system.

You are using pdflatex on windows and latex on linux. You would see the same error if you used latex on windows and it would work without error if you used pdflatex on linux.

If you need to use latex on either platform, use an image editor (or a tool such as imagemagic convert) to make a  `varsityLogo.eps` file and then latex/dvips will use the eps version and pdflatex (or lualatex or xelatex) would use the png.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, considering the `img` subfolder you have already created, you need to address your file as: `'img/varsityLogo.png'`.

Also you should use `pdflatex` instead of `latex`, since `latex` does not support reading the size of PNG, JPG or PDF images.

Maybe easiest way (Not best) to get rid of these errors while transferring your code among your operating systems, is to put the images right beside your tex file. In this case, you need to just write the filenames in address.

Comment: The issue is resolved. There was no problem in path name. It was just the matter of `latex` and `pdflatex` as [David Carlisle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) pointed in the [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330993/how-to-make-image-insertion-platform-independent/330996#comment811118_330993) of the question.

Comment: "...  is to put the images right beside your tex file" -- it would make my project massacre as there are hundreds of images and tex files (standalone) in my project.

Comment: @manetsus look up `\graphicspath`

Comment: @manetsus you can also check here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18913/paths-and-linux-windows-slash-conventions

Comment: @daleif Thanks for your suggestion. I would try to look into it. Btw, Did you miss that the issue is resolved without any editing in my tex files?

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah Thanks for your eagerness for helping me. But the issue is already resolved without changing anything in my tex files as I said above.

Comment: @manetsus sure I got that. I wrote that part only because of the address `./img/varsityLogo` you have written in the question. I just wanted to clear that up. Thanks.

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah and this addressing works on both platforms. Anyway, Thanks once again.

Comment: `./img/varsityLogo/varsityLogo.png` is OK, but you have written `./imgvarsityLogo/` in the first part of your question (without specifying the file name). I though maybe it is proper to state the addressing issue in the answer.

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah Could you please point me where I have written `./imgvarsityLogo/`? I believe, I did not write something like that in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45801/discussion-between-majid-abdolshah-and-manetsus).